# AF_UNIX usage with SOCK_DGRAM creates a problem with the unix socket name length

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, ipc

my question is about IPC using AF_UNIX and SOCK_DGRAM.
my server code after removing some error checks from the code is:

```
 sd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
 serveraddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 strcpy(serveraddr.sun_path, SERVER_PATH);
 length = BUFFER_LENGTH;
 rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVLOWAT, (char *)&length, sizeof(length));
 rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, SUN_LEN(&serveraddr));
 rc = recv(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0));
```

my client code after removing some error checks from the code is:

```
 sd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
 serveraddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 strcpy(serveraddr.sun_path, SERVER_PATH);
 memset(buffer, 'a', sizeof(buffer));
 socklen_t server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
 sendto(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, server_length);
```

the weired problem i can see lies in the definition of the SERVER_PATH.
once the length of my SERVER_PATH is more than 14 characters the client send(...) will fail with the error ("No such file or directory").

some points to notice:

- i am using redhat 64 bit.
- i have defined SERVER_PATH as follows: #define SERVER_PATH     "/tmp/aaaaaaaaaa"
- when i change the code to not use SOCK_DGRAM but SOCK_STREAM (after adding the connect, listen and accept methods to the code as shown in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/xafunixcl.htm and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6xafunixsrv.htm there is no issue with the socket name length.

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem has to do with `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`. On my system that allows 14 characters for the address field. Try `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`.

Comment: i was hoping that you found my problem, but that not the issue.
thanks.

Comment: sorry, i have re checked your suggestion, and it seems to fix my problem.
thanks a lot.